# Customize x axis tick marks in likert function from HH package

Tags: r, plot, graph, lattice, likert

I would like to customize the x axis tick marks of the output from likert function of HH package in R. 
MWE from package manual:

```
library(HH)
data("ProfChal", package = "HH")
likert(Question ~ . , data=ProfChal[EmpRows,], as.percent=TRUE,
     ylab=NULL,
     main="Is your job professionally challenging?",
     positive.order=TRUE)
```

Currently, x axis tick marks are in increments of 20 units. I would like to make it to 10 units. Note that I would still like my tick marks to the left of 0 to be positive.

Answer (score 2):

The `HH` `likert` function uses the `lattice` package for plotting (specifically the `barchart` function) and you can use standard `lattice` formatting arguments within the `likert` function. In the code below, I've added `xlim` and `scales` arguments to show how to set the axis limits and breaks, respectively.

```
likert(Question ~ . , data=ProfChal, as.percent=TRUE,
       ylab=NULL,
       main="Is your job professionally challenging?",
       positive.order=TRUE, 
       xlim=c(-50,100),
       scales=list(x=list(at=seq(-50,100,10),
                          labels=c(seq(50,0,-10),seq(10,100,10))))
       )
```

[image]